# Click the PCLVisualizer class display interface, and encounter an error

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, point-cloud-library

I created a point cloud collection system using qt+pcl as the GIF shows. However, during the data collection, If I click the display interface using the right button, I would encounter an error as the picture shows. How to solve this problem? Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pst3H.gif)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MbMt.png)

Comment: Looks like an access violation. Could be caused by undefined behavior in your code or could be a bug in one of the libraries you are using. Maybe you are running debug mode but linked to release mode binaries causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can make sure my pcl libraries are debugging mode. In fact, I tried to start a  timer to implement a similar function but I didn't encounter this error.